# Web scraping using Python and HTTPS proxies

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping

Is there currently something in Python that support HTTPS proxies for web scraping ? I am currently using Python 2.7 with Windows but I could use Python 3 if it supports HTTPS proxy protocol.

I tried using mechanize and requests but both failed on HTTPS proxy protocol.

This bit is using `mechanize`:
    import mechanize

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.set_proxies({
    "http"  : "ncproxy1.uk.net.intra:8080",
    "https" : "ncproxy1.uk.net.intra:8080",})
br.add_proxy_password("uname", "pass")

br.open("http://www.google.co.jp/")  # OK
br.open("https://www.google.co.jp/") # Proxy Authentication Required
```

or using `requests`:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

proxyDict = { 
          'http'  : 'ncproxy1.uk.net.intra:8080', 
          'https' : 'ncproxy1.uk.net.intra:8080'
        }
auth = HTTPProxyAuth('uname', 'pass')

r = requests.get("https://www.google.com", proxies=proxyDict, auth=auth)
print r.text
```

I obtain the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SRC\NuffieldLogger\NuffieldLogger\nuffieldrequests.py", line 10, in <module>
    r = requests.get("https://www.google.com", proxies=proxyDict, auth=auth)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 335, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 438, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 331, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Comment: mechanize does not support Python 3 afaik.

Answer (score 0):

For requests module you can use this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
proxy_dict = {
    'http': 'http://user:passwd@proxy_ip:port',
    'https': 'https://user:passwd@proxy_ip:port'
}
r = requests.get('https://google.com', proxies=proxy_dict)
print(r.text)
```

I have tested this.